# How to disable image edit mode on click - Redactor

Tags: jquery, css, redactor, image-editor

i am using redactor Wysiwyg. I want to disable "Image edit mode" on redactor when you click on image. as I want to apply my custom image editor on it.
Please see the attached screenshot of what I mean about disabling the image editor. You will notice that there is an "edit" label on center and image resizable handles as well.
I can modify the core redactor.js by deleting the span generator 'id="redactor-image-box"'. But is there any way to disable it when you initialize the redactor?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out that if you use following command then you will disable image edit mode and image resizable mode

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    imageEditable: false, // disable image edit mode on click
    imageResizable: false // disable image resize mode on click
});
```